# Add days to a timestamp

Tags: php

Im trying to add a certain amount of days to a timestmp using this in PHP:

```
$capturedDate = '2008-06-20'; 
$endDate = strtotime($capturedDate); 
$endDate2 = strtotime('+1 day',$endDate); 
echo $endDate2;
```

but its displaying: `1216526400`

any ideas?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime()` converts the date into a unix timestamp which is the number of seconds since January 1st 1970. If you want a date output you have to run the finished timestamp through `date()` first.

```
$capturedDate = '2008-06-20'; 
$endDate = strtotime($capturedDate.' +1 day'); 
echo date("Y-m-d", $endDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$endDate2);
```

Or (for just the date):

```
echo date("Y-m-d",$endDate2);
```

You can find documentation about how to format your string here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

You should be using DateTime for working with dates. It's timezone friendly.

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2008-06-20');
$datetime->modify('+1 day');
echo $datetime->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

[strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) creates a Unix timestamp so if you want to be presented with a formatted date, you need to pass the timestamp as an argument to the date function as follows:

```
$capturedDate = '2008-06-20'; 
$endDate = strtotime($capturedDate); 
$endDate2 = strtotime('+1 day',$endDate);
echo date('Y-m-d', $endDate2);
```

Additionally, there are a wide variety of parameters you can use in the [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function if you want to display additional information.

e.g.: `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $endDate2);` or `echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', $endDate2);`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sooooo close, just take your timestamp and convert it back into date format using `date("desired format",$endDate2);`

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is a very nice way to deal with dates. You can try like this:

```
$capturedDate = '2008-06-20'; 
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $capturedDate)->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```